# Transitioning from Asp.Net Core SignalR to Azure SignalR

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-signalr

We currently have an API that is authenticated using Azure Active Directory.
This API is accessed by our Teams App and call the Microsoft Graph (utilizing the On-Behalf-Of flow).
We are using Asp.Net Core SignalR (dotnet 6) at the moment, but we would like to transition to Azure SignalR.

We have set up the API according to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.1#built-in-jwt-authentication-1), and it is functioning as expected.

My program.cs look like this when configuring the authentication

```
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration, "AzureAd")
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
                .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

            builder.Services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    // We don't validate issuer as the application is multi tenant and can be any Azure AD tenant
                    // We don't validate audience as the application should use the OnBehalf flow
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                };

                var originalOnMessageReceived = options.Events.OnMessageReceived;
                options.Events.OnMessageReceived = async context =>
                {
                    await originalOnMessageReceived(context);

                    var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                    var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && path.StartsWithSegments(Hub.Url))
                    {
                        context.Token = accessToken;
                    }
                };
            });
```

My Hub is configured as below

```
[Authorize]
public class TeamsHub : Hub 
{
    private readonly GraphServiceClient _client;
    public TeamsHub(GraphServiceClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task ConnectUser(Guid meetingId)
    {
        if (Context.User == null) return;

        var userAadId = Context.User.Claims.GetUserAadId();

        await _client.Users[userAadId.ToString()].Presence.SetPresence("Available", "Available").Request().PostAsync();
    }
}
```

My signalR is configured as below

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR(o =>
            {
                // register the middleware as filter to enable the multi-tenant with EF Core
                o.AddFilter<MultiTenantServiceMiddleware>();
                o.AddFilter<EventLoggingHubFilter>();
                o.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            }).AddJsonProtocol(options =>
            {
                options.PayloadSerializerOptions.Converters
                    .Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
            });
```

Everything works well with Asp.Net Core SignalR. However, as soon as I add `AddAzureSignalR()`, the connection works, I receive the event, but the request to the Graph fails, stating that my user needs to perform an incremental consent.

Is there anything that i am missing ?

Comment: Have you tried to register a new user, then approve the permissions when you log in the app which use the azure signalr service. Waiting for your update.

Comment: Hello @JasonPan, yes. I've even created a new demo tenant to try this out.
As there are a lot of permissions in my app and some need admin consent, as the admin, i've consented for the entire org.

Comment: Unfortunatly no.

Comment: I do believe it's something about the `context.Token = accessToken;` because when using AzureSignalR, my breakpoint are not hit.
But inside my Hub method, i can see that the token is in the query params.

Comment: I investigated further, and the token from ASR and the one I recieve in the `OnMessageReceived ` are fondamentally different.
@JasonPan do you know if there are any sample with an Azure AD OBO flow ?

Comment: Check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code

Comment: so, i deeply investigate. I believes that azure signalr token cannot be used for token exchange for the Microsoft Graph.
To make it work, i updated my clientHub to add the token into the querystring endpoint
``signalrEndpoint+`?graph_token=${await getToken()}`` and getting it on the server side through a hub filter.
@JasonPan what do you think of this solution ?

Comment: The other idea i had was to add the token to exchange as a claim by implementing my own negatiateEndpoint as seen [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples/tree/main/samples/Management)
But it feel more complicated and i've seen that azure signalR might fail if [the token is too long](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-howto-troubleshoot-guide#access-token-too-long)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Azure Signal R token cannot be exchanged into a graph token.
To retrieve an exchangeable token, I've updated my client hub endpoint to add the token as a query string:

```
        const getToken = async () => await microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken();
        const endpoint = configurationContext.data.signalrEndpoint+`?graph_token=${await getToken()}`;
        const hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl(endpoint, { accessTokenFactory: getToken })
            .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
            .withAutomaticReconnect()
            .build();
        await hubConnection.start();
```

Then on the server side, i've added a HubFilter that retrieve the token from the query string and store it into a class resoleved through DI.

```
public class GraphTokenHubFilter : IHubFilter
{
    private readonly ISignalrGraphTokenProvider _tokenProvider;

    public GraphTokenHubFilter(ISignalrGraphTokenProvider tokenProvider)
    {
        _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Read the graph token from the query string and set it in the <see cref="ISignalrGraphTokenProvider"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="invocationContext"></param>
    /// <param name="next"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ValueTask<object> InvokeMethodAsync(HubInvocationContext invocationContext, Func<HubInvocationContext, ValueTask<object>> next)
    {
        var httpContext = invocationContext.Context.GetHttpContext();
        if (httpContext != null && httpContext.Request.Query.TryGetValue("graph_token", out var graphToken))
        {
            _tokenProvider.SetToken(graphToken);
        }
        return next(invocationContext);
    }
}
```

Finally I created a factory that either return the Standard Graph Client (for the api) or create a new one for SignalR

```
public class GraphServiceFactory : IGraphServiceFactory
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly ISignalrGraphTokenProvider _tokenProvider;
    private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;
    private readonly GraphApiOptions _graphApiOptions;
    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
    private readonly string[] _graphApiScope;
    private readonly string[] _acsScope;

    
    public GraphServiceFactory(HttpClient client, ISignalrGraphTokenProvider tokenProvider,
        ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition, IOptions<FrontOptions> frontOptions, IOptions<GraphApiOptions> graphApiOptions,
        GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
    {
        _httpClient = client;
        _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
        _graphApiOptions = graphApiOptions.Value;
        _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
        _acsScope = frontOptions.Value.AcsScopes.Split(" ");
        _graphApiScope = frontOptions.Value.GraphScopes.Split(" ");
    }

    public async Task<GraphServiceClient> GetClientAsync(GraphScope tokenScope)
    {
        var scopes = tokenScope == GraphScope.GraphApi ? _graphApiScope : _acsScope;
        try
        {
            await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(_graphApiOptions.ClientId)
                .WithClientSecret(_graphApiOptions.ClientSecret)
                .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, _graphApiOptions.TenantId)
                .Build();
            return new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async requestMessage =>
            {
                var userAssertion = _tokenProvider.Token;
                var result  = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(scopes, new UserAssertion(userAssertion)).ExecuteAsync();
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
            }), new SimpleHttpProvider(_httpClient));
        }

        return _graphServiceClient;
    }
    
}
```

It's not the state of the art, but it works for now :)